# Microsoft SQL Data Sync Agent cannot install

Tags: azure

Service 'Microsoft SQL Data Sync 2.0' could not be installed. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services.

Previously I have installed it in the same machine.

Comment: Event Viewer? Logs? What research have you done? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Finally its working

When typing the account name,
use {PCname}{accountname}